Next JS Convex Cloud Node Modules not compiling
I am creating RAG application. My Tech-Stack is NextJS, Convex for storing users data and chat-history. Astra-DB for storing my vectorized data of documents. The problem is I want to connect my Astra-DB to my application under chat.ts which is under convex folder.
The problem is whenever I use node modules to create a connection, convex compiler gives node bundle error. I am attaching error below.
In tsconfig.json of convex I have excluded the node_modules. But still it is trying to bundle it:
{
  /* This TypeScript project config describes the environment that
   * Convex functions run in and is used to typecheck them.
   * You can modify it, but some settings required to use Convex.
   */
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* These settings are not required by Convex and can be modified. */
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,

    /* These compiler options are required by Convex */
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2021", "dom"],
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["./_generated", "../node_modules", "dist"]
}


Error:

In tsconfig.json of convex I have excluded the node_modules. But still it is trying to bundle it.

Have you tried the platform key per the recommendation?

This is because you have a file in the convex folder that imports the package node-fetch. In a convex action you can use fetch directly, you don't need to import node-fetch; and node-fetch is a Node.js library, while Convex queries, mutations and actions don't run in Node.js.
If you need to use a Node.js library (for example, if an Astra-DB SDK required it) then you should create a new file in your convex folder that says
"use node";

import { action } from "./_generated/server";

export const yourAction = action((ctx, args) => {
  ...write your action here
});

where you'll be allowed to import Node.js libraries, because this file will be bundled differently and run in a Node.js environment.
